# Does Mac OS X have an Microsoft RPC equivalent?

Tags: macos, ipc, rpc

Microsoft RPC provides an IPC mechanism that can be done in a function-calling manner. This has been extremely helpful for my project where my main service delegates tasks to a child process, and functions in the child process can be called as if they were implemented in the main service. That takes away the burden of having to serialize abstract data and define custom protocols when using other IPC mechanisms such as named pipes, sockets, protobuf, etc. I'm aware that RPC does use them internally.

I've read an article on [implementing COM for Mac OS X](http://www.macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2004/04/16/com_osx.html?page=2) which is probably the closest thing to what I need. If I find no other no other way of implementing the type of IPC I need, I'm probably going to go with COM, but I thought I'd make sure that I'm not missing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at ["XPC Services"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/Chapters/DesigningDaemons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW4-SW3). From the documentation:

> XPC services are managed by launchd and provide services to a single
>   application. They are typically used to divide an application into
>   smaller parts. This can be used to improve reliability by limiting the
>   impact if a process crashes, and to improve security by limiting the
>   impact if a process is compromised.

And later in that guide:

> The `NSXPCConnection` API is an Objective-C-based API that provides a
>   remote procedure call mechanism, allowing the client application to
>   call methods on proxy objects that transparently relay those calls to
>   corresponding objects in the service helper and vice-versa.

Comment: I should have initially mentioned this, but I require it to work on 10.7+ (NSXPCConnection API is from 10.8) and I need to be able to have the child process be able to run in either system or user context. XPC services can only be run in user context. I will probably end up using COM, but since everyone's requirement is different, I'll mark this as the answer.